# ASP.NET SmtpClient Considerations

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, smtpclient

We are currently sending e-mails from our two load balanced web servers that connect to a separate MailEnable server, which we want to sunset. We want to have both web servers send their own e-mail using the Smtp service/IIS/.net SmtpClient. I have everything set up and configured to do this and it's working fine, but is there anything else aside from the basic configuration that I need to take into consideration? Some specific examples:

- I initially tried using Amazon SES but it was not a good solution for us. Is there any huge pitfall of having the Smtp service handle e-mails to the degree that I should still be considering a 3rd party service?
- Our web servers have decent specs in terms of processor, RAM, bandwidth, etc., but will the Smtp service consume a significant amount of resources if it's sending 100-500 e-mails/day?
- When I was using Amazon SES, they gave me 1 TXT record and 3 CNAME (DKIM) records to enter in our DNS records. Are these needed, and if so, how can I generate them on my own? I read some documentation on formatting standards but I don't really understand what step 1 is as far as how to just figure out what the values should be.
- Is there anything going on behind the scenes with 3rd party services, whether its Amazon SES, MailEnable, Exchange, etc. as far as spam control, queuing, etc. that the Smtp service/IIS doesn't handle?

I would also appreciate any other advice you can share. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sending these emails to Internet recipients (e.g. customers), @GoatBreeder?  Do they contain any marketing or transactional content?

Comment: 90% of the e-mails will be sent from our domain, to our domain - mostly error e-mails, alerts, and notifications. The other 10% are things like order receipts, account registration, etc. sent from our domain to external domains. On occasion, it may be used for sending very small bulk mailings - "very small" being dozens to potentially a few hundred recipients.

Comment: Thanks, @GoatBreeder.  This helps a lot, and I will follow with answers to all points that you raised.  One other question to provide appropriate answers: do you intend to receive mail (e.g. replies) with these servers as well - or just send mail?

Comment: @J0e3gan, thanks, I really appreciate the help! We will only be sending, no receiving.

Comment: I don't know whether SO sends a notification to you for an edit to an answer to your question, @GoatBreeder; but edit it for completeness I did.  HTH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Not really.  Like any service, it depends on your competencies and resources relative to the task versus available service providers'.  Besides adequate server resources and bandwidth, administration is something to consider for reliability and security of course.  For example:

  - You probably want to be sure that errors or service stoppages don't go unnoticed.  Properly addressed messages not being sent or being sent belatedly and causing confusion - not good.
  - You should be able to ensure that you appropriately disallow/restrict remote connections and relaying.
- No, 100-500 emails per day per server should not consume significant resources.
- As far as the DNS records:

  - They are probably unnecessary for your intradomain messages.
  - If you want friendly, mail-dedicated host names in these messages' headers (i.e. the CNAME record(s)), weigh it against your competencies and resources as in my reply to your first point (i.e. whether you have a DNS server and someone who knows what to do with it).  If the servers are in an Active Directory domain, AD probably provides resolvable (if not mail-specific) host names already; but bare IP addresses in the headers harm no one.
  - I have not personally encountered a need for DKIM (i.e. the TXT record) with intradomain messages and doubt that you need it.
  - For your interdomain messages to outside recipients, DNS adjustments are probably more important.  If you happen to have a public DNS server and someone who knows what to do with it, consider adding appropriate records there; if not, consider having your ISP or a dedicated DNS provider handle it.
- If you accepted inbound mail, spam would be a concern.  In my experience with services for outbound mail, the benefits matter more in high-volume B2C situations with marketing and transactional emails - e.g. established mail-host reputations and appropriate DNS configurations to help avoid messages being rejected or mislabeled as spam, message templating etc.